# How to update dom element in certain interval of time in dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-html, dart-webui

I want to create a text typing effect in simple web application. It's my first time using dart for web application. I did something like this.

```
var chars = "Hello World".split('');
    var textstream = Stream<String>.fromIterable(chars);

    var idx = 0;
    textstream.listen((data) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: idx * 200), () {
        var element = querySelector('#hero-keyword');
        element.appendText(data);
        idx++;
      });
    });
```

And my html has this

```
<p id="hero-keyword"></p>
```

But, I want each letter printed in the interval of 200ms. But what I got is, all letters show up at the same time.

Comment: Asynchronous stuff doesn't work like loops. idx will not be updated until the delayed future completes.

The `fromIterable` stream will emit all it's values "at once", but the delayed futures will each wait until the next pass of the event loop. Effectively, this means you're delaying every future with a delay of `0`.

Maybe instead of `fromIterable`, try `Stream.periodic`, and on each period, emit the `computationCount`th character of your original string?

Answer (score 0):

Your `idx` variable is only being updated when the delayed future completes, which will happen on the first pass of the event loop *after* the specified delay.

`fromIterable`, however, will process its values all at once, in sequence. Taken together, the net effect is that all of your delays are being set to `0`, and then, after a slight delay, all of your characters will be emitted, and `idx` will be incremented.

You can try the following pattern, instead, adjusted to your use case:

```dart
void main() {
  var text = "Hello world";
  Stream
    .periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 200), (count) {
      print(text[count]);
    })
   .take(text.length)
   .drain();
}
```